# CTE con subconsultas en anchor y llamada recursiva

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Resulta que tengo estas tres tablas,

`Users(id, name)`

`Colleagues(id1, id2)`

`Friends(id1, id2)`

Necesito escribir una consulta que me entregue pares de ids tal que se pueda "llegar" del id1 al id2 con una cantidad arbitraria de colegas y/o amigos.Es decir, id1 esta conectado con id2 a traves de una cierta cantidad de colegas o amigos.
Puedo hacer una consulta que me entrega todos los amigos alcanzables o colegas alcanzables, pero no he logrado usar ambos para construir las conexiones.
Supuse que podría hacerlo con subconsultas de la siguiente manera:

```
WITH RECURSIVE Reachable (id_1, id_2)
AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        FRIENDS.id2
    FROM
        USERS,
        FRIENDS
    WHERE
        FRIENDS.id1 = USERS.id
    UNION
    SELECT
        id,
        COLLEAGUES.id2
    FROM
        USERS,
        COLLEAGUES
    WHERE
        COLLEAGUES.id1 = USERS.id)
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        REACHABLE.id_1,
        FRIENDS.id2
    FROM
        REACHABLE,
        FRIENDS
    WHERE
        REACHABLE.id_2 = FRIENDS.id1
    UNION
    SELECT
        REACHABLE.id_1,
        COLLEAGUES.id2
    FROM
        REACHABLE,
        COLLEAGUES
    WHERE
        REACHABLE.id_2 = COLLEAGUES.id1));
```

Pero se genera este error:

`Error: near line 1: recursive reference in a subquery: Reachable`

Significa que no puedo usar llamadas recursivas en subconsultas en general o es otro problema?
Acaso se puede hacer la consulta que necesito usando solo una CTE?
Gracias de antemano!